# Sling 7 JCR SQL Query Fails On Unicode-Value Properties

Tags: sql, jcr, jackrabbit, sling

I'm implementing a WCMS using Apache Sling 7.

In the tree I have some nodes with unicode values, for example,

I have a node with a property named `pname('بابک بهزادی')` and another node with `pname('babak behzadi')`. When I execute a query on pname field with unicode values query returns nothing:

```
select * from nt:unstructured where pname like '%بابک%'
```

but, if I execute the same query with non-unicode values it returns some results

```
select * from nt:unstructured where pname like '%babak%'
```

Queries above are SQL not SQL-2.

In addition, I've never had such a problem with Apache Sling 6.

**EDIT:**

Apache Sling works perfectly with these Jackrabbit bundles:

[image]

and fails with these bundles:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is most likely related to the Jackrabbit version used. Can you post the Jackrabbit version that works and the one that does not work?

Comment: I've edited my question and added Jackrabbit bundles versions.

Comment: If you can debug the Sling code, it would be interesting to check the request that's passed to the Jackrabbit modules, to verify whether the problem lies on the Sling or Jackrabbit side. If I'm not mistaken, setting a breakpoint on the findResources or queryResources methods of the JcrResourceProvider should let you see what's happening (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/jcr/resource/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/jcr/resource/internal/helper/jcr/JcrResourceProvider.java)